# hasOwnProperty doesn't exist in some browsers

Tags: javascript

After an ajax request, I make some validation to ensure that the response contains the expected properties before going forward, using hasOwnProperty:

```
var validateResponseFormat = function (response) {
    var properties = ["StatusCode", "Response"];
    var result = {
        status: true,
        propertyNotFound: null
    };

    if (!response) {
        result.status = false;
        result.propertyNotFound = "response is null";
        return result;
    }

    for (var index in properties) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty(properties[index]) === false) {
            result.status = false;
            result.propertyNotFound = properties[index];
            return result;
        }
    }

    return result;
};


var response = {"Response":{"DebugMode":false,"ProvidersToCall":[{"ProviderId":"1234","Settings":null}]},"Status":"Success","StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":""};

var isResponseFormatValid = validateResponseFormat(response);
if (isResponseFormatValid.status === false) {
    return badformaterror(isResponseFormatValid.propertyNotFound);
}
```

In production, this code works well except that sometimes it outputs a weird error:

```
bad format: function (){try{var _0x5757=["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D","\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72"],_0xa438x1=this[_0x5757[0]],_0xa438x2,_0xa438x3;if(_0xa438x1==0){return};while(--_0xa438x1){_0xa438x2=Math[_0x5757[2]](Math[_0x5757[1]]()*(_0xa438x1+1));_0xa438x3=this[_0xa438x1];this[_0xa438x1]=this[_0xa438x2];this[_0xa438x2]=_0xa438x3;};}catch(e){}finally{return this}}
```

Do you know what is happening ?
As far as I checked, hasOwnProperty was supported on all browsers (even old IEs).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: shouldn't really use `for in` on array and `hasOwnProperty()` returns boolean, no need for `=== false`

Comment: In old Safari (v 0.2 or similar), there was no *hasOwnProperty* or it was buggy, I forget which, so [*propertyIsEnumerable*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.propertyisenumerable) was used instead. It does pretty much exactly the same thing.

Comment: Agree with Charlietfl, you can probably use *every*: `if (!properties.every(function(prop){return  response.hasOwnProperty(prop)}))` or similar.

Comment: @LucasRoss—context? Perhaps you meant `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(...)`, but if `response.hasOwnProperty` doesn't call the method with *response* as *this*, there are some seriously fundamental issues with the host implementation.

Comment: charlietfl I agree, I'll change my code according to it. @RobG thanks for the information ! Even if I don't think that an old safari causes more than 500 errors yesterday, that's interesting. I didn't think of every, that's a nice idea :) I could use  `hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)` but I don't think that it will resolve my issue though.

Comment: @VivienAdnot—with arrow functions (not widely available yet) an *every* solution becomes much more concise: `if (!properties.every(prop=>response.hasOwnProperty(prop)))`.